# How to add mouse event handler on MenuItem

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I have this code:

```
System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem^ item = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem("text");
item->Click += ...
```

How can I add a mouse event handler to item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define an event handler method with the expected signature:

```
void ItemClicked(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
    // your code
}
```

Then you register it by using the `+=` operator:

```
item->Click += gcnew EventHandler(&ItemClicked); // if ItemClicked is static
item->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &ItemClicked); // if instance
```